# C# Array strings in a Group of Radio Buttons

Tags: c#, radio-button, file.readalllines

My code is C# windows form
I have a file with data: 

David One And Two/Three 
Alex One Two Four And Five/Six 
 
Amanda Two Seven/Ten 
Micheal Seven/Nine

and trying to have them in array like

```
string[] Names = File.ReadAllLines("C:\Students\Name.txt", Encoding.Default);
```

and have them in Group of Radio Buttons

```
RadioButton[] n = new RadioButton[Names.Length];

for (int i = 0; i < Names.Length; i++)
 {
   n[i] = new RadioButton();
   n[i].Text = Names[i];
   n[i].Location = new Point(10, 10 + i * 20);
   groupBox1.Controls.Add(n[i]);
 }
```

But it shows as my attached image 
I tried without Encoding.Default and Encoding.UTF8 but the same problem.

What is I'am doing wrong? Please see my image and help me. Thank you in advance!

[image]

Comment: It sounds like you're asking two questions here.  Didn't you already ask the one about reading the file just yesterday?  Is that one gone?  I never saw an answer about the format of the file's line endings: `lf` or `crlf`?

Comment: @clarkitect thank you for quick respons. I'am sorry  , yes it's allmost the same question actually I want my array strings in a radiobutton. By the way What it the meaning of  lf or crlf? What do you mean by that? Sorry I'am new for thos short words.. ;)

Comment: `lf` is short for "line feed" and `cr` is short for "carriage return" which is a really old-fashioned name for "hard return."  The characters within the file that terminate each "line" of the file.  We haven't really seen the actual file in your example because it's pasted as plain text rather than code (or a link to pastebin or something).  The result you're seeing puts the contents of the file into question.  The other possibility is that the radio button's label is interpreting that `/` character somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm guessing your file contains empty lines at the end. You can try to remove them before creating a radio button:

```
for (int i = 0; i < Names.Length; i++)
 {
   var name = Names[i];
   if(name.Trim() == string.Empty) continue;

   n[i] = new RadioButton();
   n[i].Text = Names[i];
   n[i].Location = new Point(10, 10 + i * 20);
   groupBox1.Controls.Add(n[i]);
 }
```

If your text is trimmed you can try to increase the width of the control:

```
n[i].Width = 300; // Put a value which will show the entire text
```

Comment: Thank you for response, yes  you are right my file contains empty lines and now it's fixed, but stil the same problem I just can show the part of every line not the hole line as a string. I expected as image 1 not like image 2. Please help me...

Comment: Try to increase the width of the control

Comment: Mariusz Jamro , thank you very much, now it's working as expected.